# Составить словарь из имени и действия человека

Tags: python, словари, генераторы

```
p = 'Иван ест, поет Оля'
a = []
m = p.split(',')
for i in range(len(m)):
    z = m[i].split()
    a.append(z)
    d = {k: v for k,v in a if v.islower and k.isupper}
print(d)
```

программа выводит {'Иван': 'ест', 'поет': 'Оля'}
А должна выводить {'Иван': 'ест', 'Оля': 'поет}
В чем ошибка?

Comment: Ни в чем. Первое слово - ключ, второе - значение. Если нужно чтобы ключом было был субъект, вторым - действие, нужно как-то их различать. В данном случае можно определять имя по большой букве, но если бы было "Ест Иван", как бы вы определили где имя, а где действие? На данный момент задача слишком широкая. При желании можно прикрутить например [Pymorphy2](http://pymorphy2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), и на основании разбора пытаться наванговать часть речи (с определенной долей вероятности, т.е. не со 100% точностью).

Answer (score 3):

Т.к. в задаче не было конкретики, то пришлось по примеру в вопрос придумать ограничения, например: ключом является слово в верхнем регистре, которое может быть первым  или последним словом в команде, а значение – все, что не ключ:

```
text = 'Иван ест, поет Оля, Илья ответит на вопрос, задаст вопрос Алексей'

command_dict = dict()

for command in text.split(', '):
    words = command.split()

    # Проверяем что первый символ слова в верхнем регистре
    if words[0][0].isupper():
        key = words[0]
        value = ' '.join(words[1:])

    else:
        key = words[-1]
        value = ' '.join(words[:-1])

    command_dict[key] = value

print(command_dict)
```

Консоль:

```
{'Илья': 'ответит на вопрос', 'Алексей': 'задаст вопрос', 'Иван': 'ест', 'Оля': 'поет'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ваше условие при генерации словаря вам не помогает. Необходимо пару "ключ-значение" "обернуть" функцией, которая приведёт её в желаемый вид, например такую:

```
def find_isupper(x):
    """
    >>>  print ' '.join(find_isupper([u'Иван', u'ест']))
    Иван ест
    >>> print ' '.join(find_isupper([u'поет', u'Оля']))
    Оля поет
    """
    if len(x) == 2 and x[0][0].isupper():
        t = x
    elif len(x) == 2 and x[1][0].isupper():
        t = x[::-1]
    else:
        t = []
    return t
```